# How to write a web page to a txt file and using the first line as a variable

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to set a variable on my bash script to the output of a url web page.
All the web page does is display the latest build number of our product so it will only be a number that is displayed, but I am trying to get that number and set it to a variable.

Can this be done and if so can anyone shed any light on it for me.

Comment: Look at `curl` perhaps. Run `curl` on the web address, which will return the HTML contents, then parse out the build number (perhaps with `grep`, `sed`, or `awk`). Hard to say beyond that without more detail. It would help if you could show the actual HTML contents of the page you are referring to.

Comment: The actual web page itself just shows a number, white background and a number in the top corner. For example today it is `23` and tomorrow it will be `24` and so forth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
MYVAR=$(wget -q -O - "http://myserver/mypath" | head -1)
```

or

```
MYVAR=$(curl "http://myserver/mypath" | head -1)
```

If the page has only one line then `head -1` may not be necessary.

Comment: It's unclear whether the web page the OP is referring to have the build number on the first line or not. Even though it may appear as one line in a web browser, there could be lots of HTML header information. It also might be wrapped in HTML such as `<p>build_number</p>`. The OP hasn't specified.

Comment: @mbratch you may be right, Dan: can you clarify whether the webpage displays html content or just the build number as plain text?

Comment: no it is literally just the build number and nothing else. Does your code take the data from the web page and turn it into a variable?

Comment: @Dan this code should do what you're asking for. Try it and see. :) Based upon your description, you probably don't need `| head -1`.